# String Object Return

Tags: java

I wanted to make sure that this code is returning a string object.

```
class ShoutBox extends Clone{

  public static String ShoutOutRandomMessage(){
      //holds the words to be generated.

      String[] subject= {" Jim is", " Henry is", " Carter is"};
      String[] verb= {" eating", " catching", " studying", " caughing"};
      String[] adjective= {" funny", " hard", " good", " polite"};
      String[] object= {" course", " homework", " books", " dog"};
      String[] adverb= {" quickly. ", " everywhere. ", " accordingly. ", " awfully. "};

       Random r = new Random(); //intialize a Random
       int selectedElement = r.nextInt(subject.length);
     {


         //This Method will grab a word from the above list.
            String randomSentence = subject[selectedElement]
                    + verb[selectedElement]
                    + adjective[selectedElement]
                    + object[selectedElement]
                    + adverb[selectedElement];
            System.out.println("Here is your Random Generated Sentence"+"\n");
            System.out.println(randomSentence + "\n\n");
            //This method will print the random sentence.

            return String.format(randomSentence);
     } 
           //Is this code returning a string object.

     }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If it is not returning *a* String, what is it returning? Anyway, the inner `{}`'s are superfluous and can be removed without changing the program.

Comment: When you declare a method as having a return type of `String`, that means it can either return a reference to a `String` object, or it can return `null`, or it can throw an `Exception` or an `Error`, or it can fail to terminate.  There are no other options.  And in your case, yes, this returns a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to return `String.format(randomSentence)`. Just return `randomSentence`. `String.format(randomSentence)` does return a String, but it will be equal to `randomSentence`, since you are not passing to the `format` method any additional parameters.